# What is "Medium Armor"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I join the Legion, I'm able to get some equipment.  The Blacksmith asks if I want light, medium or heavy armor.

I did not have any good save points nearby so I couldn't reload to find out what the "medium" armor option meant.

Obviously light meant light armor, and heavy meant heavy armor, but what equipment do you get if you choose medium?

Comment: Could it mean: Light (Robes), Medium (Light), Heavy (Heavy)? Otherwise I have not heard of Medium armour, there are no skill trees for it and it doesn't really make sense either...

Comment: @theorise Oooh good point, hadn't thought about that. Some confirmation would be nice though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The Blacksmith asks if I want light, medium or heavy armor.  what equipment do you get if you choose medium?

When you make the choice, you get a shield, chest, legs, hands and boots according to:

```
Choice | Shield                | Chest               | Legs, Hands, Boots
Light  | Imperial light shield | Imperial light      | Imperial light
Medium | Imperial shield ^1    | Imperial studded ^2 | Imperial light
Heavy  | Imperial shield ^1    | Imperial heavy      | Imperial heavy
```

Note<sup>1</sup>: The Imperial shield is a heavy armor item.

Note<sup>2</sup>: The Imperial studded chest is a light armor item.

Answer (score 5):

There is no Medium Armor* in Skyrim, the only available types are `Light` and `Heavy Armor`.

The blacksmith was meaning by medium armor a mixture of light and heavy armor.

*: Morrowind *had* medium armor, but it was not very practical.

Comment: I'm aware that there is no such thing as medium armor. As to the question that you answered in the end, do you know that for a fact, or are you just guessing?

Comment: I did the mission twice now, and on the second run chose medium armor for a change. Expecting some unique stuff, all I got was some light-heavy armor mixture.

Comment: You are right, I edited out the I beat around the bush for the most part.

Comment: medium armour was great in morrowind. Ebony mail, bonemould and orcish :D

Answer (score -2):

Well, it goes like this.
Medium Armour is like light armour but completely at its maximum of it's rating. Doesn't weigh you down but still, it's just armour improvement.
Clothing
Lightly
Light
Medium
Heavy 
Heavier
And Most Heavily armours with high cap ratings.